# abstract code metric generation with python

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to get information from source code files written in python and java. But my aim is an abstract or extendable solution.

I would like to get things like:

- order of functions
- parameters from function
- intends
- counting loops
- imports
- abstract syntax tree

My first idea was to use linter like pylint and checkstyle and call them from python and parse that result.

Then I found antlr which has a python and java grammar and can create lexer and parser for each language. Version 4 seems to support python.

Does anyone come up with a tool or other idea to get my information ?

Or tell me if antlr would be a good way to get an abstract way for solving this problem?